# Delete request redirecting too fast using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

so I'm using React-Router to make a simple blog page. The DELETE request works fine, however it redirects to the index page before the post has been deleted, causing an error if you click on said post (id is not defined). I have set up a call back on the action creator to ensure the request finishes before redirecting, as well as on the deletePost function that is being called. However it is still redirecting before the request finishes deleting, thanks for taking a look!

posts_show.js with onDeleteClick function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchPost } from '../actions';
import { deletePost } from '../actions';

class PostsShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchPost(id);
  }
  onDeleteClick() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;
    if(!post) {
      return <div> Loading.. </div>
    }
    return <div className="container">
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <h6>Categories: {post.categories}</h6>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-secondary">
          Back
        </Link>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-2"
              onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}
        >Delete</Link>
      </div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
  return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost })(PostsShow);
```

actions/index.js with deletePost request

```
import axios from 'axios';


export const FETCH_POSTS = 'fetch_posts';
export const CREATE_POST = 'create_post';
export const FETCH_POST = 'fetch_post';
export const DELETE_POST = 'delete_post';
const ROOT_URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=dmitriiiii88';

export function fetchPosts() {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`)
  return {
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
    payload: request
  }
}

export function createPost(values, callback) {
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, values)
    .then(() => callback());
  return {
    type: CREATE_POST,
    payload: request
  }
}

export function fetchPost(id) {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`)

  return {
    type: FETCH_POST,
    payload: request
  }
}

export function deletePost(id, callback) {
  const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`)
    .then(() => callback());

  return {
    type: DELETE_POST,
    payload: id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action is returning the type / payload object before your API call finishes.

If you aren't already, you need to use some sort of redux middleware to allow you to return a function.

[redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga) are both good options

You need to create your store and pass in the middleware like so:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from  './reducers';

export default(initialState) => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
}
```

Then in you actions, you can return a function which dispatches your action to your reducer:

```
export function deletePost(id, callback) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`)
            .then(() => {
                return {
                    type: DELETE_POST,
                    payload: id
                }
            }.catch(err => console.log(`err: ${err}`))

    }
}
```

Notice you don't need to assign your axios call to a variable either.